# Filtering noise with python pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter, scipy

I have set of data points (just x,z points) and I want to filter and get rid of out of range data points. Some of the points are way off (for example, see circled ones)

[image]

I tried this but it just smoothed it.

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
w = savgol_filter(df['data'], 20, 2)
plt.plot(df.index, w, 'b')  # high frequency noise removed
```

Comment: It's really difficult to answer that question, since removing outliers can be done with a lot of different strategies depending on the data you work with and the assumption you do. I encourange to post your question in another se forum as Math overflow or signal processing exchange. However, a simple strategy can be done using standard deviation or MAD distance ...

Comment: looking at your data i would use a std filter to reject outliers (you could replace the outlier with mean value or something like that).